Как разрешить доступ к bluetooth для userland?
Всех приветствую.
Мне нужна была виртуальная машина с linux на андройд. Я выбрал приложение userland и установил кали линукс. Теперь мне нужно из этой виртуальной машины получить доступ к bluetooth модулю. Я пытался делать это от root (sudo hсitool scan) но получил ошибку доступа:
Device is not available: Permission denied

Все возможные разрешения приложению выданы:

(Извиняюсь за большие картинки, не знаю как сделать их меньше)
И вот у меня появился вопрос:
Как предоставить доступ к bluetooth для userland?

никак. блютус модуль занят андроидом и он его не отдаст.
